# Increasing understanding of callback method when implementing map on a Prototype

Tags: javascript

```
var s = [23, 65, 98, 5];

Array.prototype.myMap = function (callback) {
  var newArray = []; 
  this.forEach(function (a) {
    return newArray.push(callback(a));
  }); 
  return newArray;
};

var new_s = s.myMap(function (item) {
  return item * 2;
});
```

`myMap` is a function we have defined that has a param called `callback`
inside `myMap` is a `forEach` that executes a function once on each array element. It's this line I don't understand

```
return newArray.push(callback(a));
```

so `push()` to `newArray`

**MDN push()**: - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

But `push()` accepts only one parameter. So why do we have `.push(callback(a))` why not just `.push(a)`?

Comment: `return` inside `forEach` is meaningless.

Comment: I think you are just confused for whatever reason. `.push(callback(a))` can easily be replaced with `var result = callback(a); ...push(result);` which shows more clearly that this is only one argument. Have never passed the result of a function call to another function call?

Answer (score 1):

> But push() accepts only one parameter. So why do we have .push(callback(a))

The return value of `callback(a)` **is** only one parameter.

> why not just .push(a)?

The point of mapping is to take an array of data and create a new array where **each item is transformed** in some way.

If you didn't pass `a` through the callback function, it wouldn't be transformed, and you'd just be making a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `push(callback(a))` denotes that:

- `push()` itself accepts one param, a callback, which...
- ...is automatically passed one param (the iterative array item)

Answer (score 0):

`callback(a)` is indeed one object, or parameter in this case. The `push` will push the result of the call to `callback(a)` to the array. It's effectively the same as this:

```js
var item = callback(a);
newArray.push(item);
```

But you're pushing the result of `callback` directly, rather than storing it in a variable first.